# C# MVC local database creation while App Start

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

When the app runs for the first time with a new connection string name it creates the Local Database files in the App_DATA folder, but it doesn't recreate it for the 2nd time if the database files missing in the App_DATA folder... Will have to change the database name given in the connectionstring. Why?

How to solve this problem?

Where it stores the state that the database has been created for the first time...
How it does the comparison/check to confirm whether the database has been created during an app start previously?

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebDemo-20210104031025.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebDemo-20210104031025;Integrated Security=True"
```

it knows the database "aspnet-WebDemo-20210104031025" has been created and looks for it in the App_Data folder. doesn't re-create it for the 2nd time when it is not available in the folder

** Didn't use code to create custom tables, just only the basic template comes with Visual Studio 2017 MVC web application including authentication(not azure- just user creation with email and so on....)

Comment: What database provider are you using? What code do you have to init the db?

Comment: local DB - that runs without sql server
I haven't done any coding. just opened the VS 2017 MVC Project with authentication. Thats all